# Python Selenium Rename Download PDF

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a web scraping program to download the newest version of these pdf documents and am running into trouble trying to figure out how to rename the pdf file before it is downloaded. Any help would be apprecieted, here is my code.

```
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

url  = 'http://aogweb.state.ak.us/WebLink/0/doc/18690/Page1.aspx'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
tgt = "G:\Well Schematics\Well Histories"
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],"download.default_directory" : tgt, "download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
chrome.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
chrome.find_element_by_id('PdfDialog_PdfDownloadLink').click()
time.sleep(2)
chrome.find_element_by_name('PdfDialog:PageRangeBox').clear()
chrome.find_element_by_name('PdfDialog:PageRangeBox').send_keys('1-30')
chrome.find_element_by_name('PdfDialog:download').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Duplicates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548041/selenium-give-file-name-when-downloading.

Comment: Selenium does not provide a way to change the name of download file, and only work with webdriver so you need to use `os` to change the name of downloaded file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium give file name when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548041/selenium-give-file-name-when-downloading)