# Download file through Google Chrome in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm do me code in Cromedrive in 'normal' mode and works fine. When I change to headless mode it don't download the file. I already try the code I found alround internet, but didn't work.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'{}/chromedriver'.format(os.getcwd()))
self.driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
self.driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': os.getcwd()}}
self.driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Anyone have any idea about how solve this problem?

PS: I don't need to use Chomedrive necessarily. If it works in another drive it's fine for me.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium/47366981#47366981 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778991/selenium-does-not-download-with-options-passed-to-the-chrome-driver/56779396#56779396)

Comment: This is exactly the code I post.

Comment: Just use regular mode and run it with xvfb-run

Comment: Just use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347178/3124333

Answer (score 31):

### First the solution

> ## Minimum Prerequisites:
>
> - *Selenium* client version: [Selenium v3.141.59](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.141/)
> - *Chrome* version: Chrome v77.0
> - *ChromeDriver* version: [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/)

To download the file clicking on the element with text as **Download Data** within [this website](https://www.mockaroo.com/) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', service_args=["--log-path=./Logs/DubiousDan.log"])
  print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
  params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'C:\Users\Debanjan.B\Downloads'}
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
  driver.get("https://www.mockaroo.com/")
  driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 250)"); 
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#download"))).click()
  print ("Download button clicked")
  #driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Headless Chrome Initialized
  Download button clicked
  ```
- File Downloading snapshot:

[image: ChromeHeadlessDownload]

---

### Details

Downloading files through [Headless Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) was one of the most sought functionality since [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) was introduced.

Since then there were different work-arounds published by different contributors and some of them are:

- [Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium)
- [Python equivalent of a given wget command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346872/python-equivalent-of-a-given-wget-command)

Now the, the good news is *Chromium* team have officially announced the arrival of the functionality **Downloading file through `Headless Chromium`**.

---

In the discussion [Headless mode doesn't save file downloads](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2454) [@eseckler](https://bugs.chromium.org/u/1164142555/) mentioned:

> Downloads in headless work a little differently. There's the `Page.setDownloadBehavior` devtools command to set a download folder. We're working on a way to use DevTools network interception to stream the downloaded file via DevTools as well.

A detailed discussion can be found at [Issue 696481: Headless mode doesn't save file downloads](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481)

Finally, [@bugdroid](https://bugs.chromium.org/u/3779532838/) revision seems to have nailed the issue for us.

---

### [ChromeDriver] Added support for headless mode to download files

> Previously, Chromedriver running in headless mode would not properly download files due to the fact it sparsely parses the preference file given to it. Engineers from the headless chrome team recommended using DevTools's "Page.setDownloadBehavior" to fix this. This changelist implements this fix. Downloaded files default to the current directory and can be set using download_dir when instantiating a chromedriver instance. Also added tests to ensure proper download functionality.

Here is the [revision](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/8e93021e7a68321de6789f1d9efd4a722bd72ac4) and [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8e93021e7a68321de6789f1d9efd4a722bd72ac4)

From [ChromeDriver v77.0.3865.40 (2019-08-20)](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt) release notes:

```
Resolved issue 2454: Headless mode doesn't save file downloads [Pri-2]
```

---

### Solution

- Update *ChromeDriver* to  latest [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- Update *Chrome* to  *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- **Note**: *Chrome v77.0* is yet to be GAed/pushed for release so till then you can download and install a development build and test either from:

  - [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/canary/)
  - Latest build from the [Dev Channel](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)

---

### Outro

However **Mac OSX** users have a wait for their pie as [On Chromedriver, headless chrome crashes after sending Page.setDownloadBehavior on MacOSX](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=979847).

Comment: @CBury Please ensure the _Chrome beta_ version is **v77.0**

Comment: I've updated my chrome and chromedrive to 77 and still don't download

Comment: Is there another way to set download_dir?

Comment: @ShinichiMaeshima Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: your example is working however I have used the same piece of code for setting up selenium to download in headless chrome and it's not working

Comment: I really wish this worked... they only added the functionality to v77.0? and subsequently took it out? using chromedriver v79  and selenium 4.0 but nothing here seems to have worked for downloading a PDF

Comment: @DebanjanB Looks like a fix for this is coming in chromium v83 - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3120#c10

Comment: YASS driver.execute_cdp_cmd fixed my issue. THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

**Chomedriver Version: 95.0.4638.54** 
**Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69**

```
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options    
 
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')    
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": "C:\\link\\to\\folder",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
        }
    )
```

What seemed to work was that I used "\\" instead of "/" for the address. The latter approach didn't throw any error, but didn't download any documents either. But, using double back slashes did the job.

Comment: I've been searching on this for a whole day, until I see your answer. THANK YOU for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

For javascript use below code:

```
    const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
    let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments('--headless --window-size=1500,1200');
    options.setUserPreferences({ 'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": Download_File_Path });
    driver = await new webdriver.Builder().setChromeOptions(options).forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

**Then switch tabs as soon as you click the download button:**

```
    await driver.sleep(1000); 
    var Handle = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
    await driver.switchTo().window(Handle[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This C# works for me

Note the new headless option https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

```
private IWebDriver StartBrowserChromeHeadlessDriver()
{
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless=new");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadFolder);

    var chromeDownload = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "behavior", "allow" },
        { "downloadPath", downloadFolder }
    };

    var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverFolder, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSecs));
    driver.ExecuteCdpCommand("Browser.setDownloadBehavior", chromeDownload);
    return driver;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
options.add_argument("--headless=new");
```

I tried everything else. Adding that line is what worked for me.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new");
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": "C:\\Path\\To\\Directory", "download.directory_upgrade": True, "download.prompt_for_download": False})

driver_path = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Driver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pathlib
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
    "behavior": "allow",
    "downloadPath": str(pathlib.Path.home().joinpath("Downloads"))
})
```

Answer (score -7):

I don't think you should be using the browser for downloading content, leave it to Chrome developers/testers.

I believe you should rather get [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) of the element you want to download and obtain it using [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)

If your site requires authentication you could fetch [cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) from the browser instance and pass them to [requests.Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Comment: This was my first try, but the href attribute is: href="javascript:void(0)"