# Element isn't clickable in headless mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

My code is very simple: click on a href link to download a file. It works fine until I add the headless argument, then clicking it doesn't do anything. Unsure whether this is a Selenium issue or a Chromedriver issue? None of the solutions I've found online have been helpful, so any suggestions would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class Scraper(object):

    def __init__(self, cursor):
        self.driver = None

    def create_driver(self):
        # Set up Headless Chrome
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("path to chromedriver"),
                                   chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def go_to_website(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/6202.0Nov%202019?OpenDocument')
        link_to_click = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/log?openagent&6202012.xls&6202.0')]")
        link_to_click.click()

    def run(self):
        # set a new driver
        self.create_driver()
        self.go_to_website()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your usecase is to click the <kbd>.xls</kbd> element for the element with text as *...Table 12. Labour force status by Sex, State and Territory - Trend, Seasonally adjusted and Original...* you to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#details tbody tr:nth-of-type(13) td>a>img"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='listentry']/td[contains(., 'Labour force status by Sex, State and Territory - Trend, Seasonally adjusted and Original')]//following::td[1]/a/img"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

However being able to click on the element through the *Locator Strategies* maynot initiate the download. To initiate the downloading using [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) you have to configure `Page.setDownloadBehavior` through `execute_cdp_cmd()` and you can find a detailed discussion in [Download file through Google Chrome in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599776/download-file-through-google-chrome-in-headless-mode/57606294#57606294)

Comment: Thanks for your help, though both options you suggested still only work when the driver's not in headless mode. When I try it in headless mode the file doesn't get downloaded.

Comment: @Uncle_Timothy This answer was to get rid of the error `element isn't clickable`. To download in headless mode needs some more configuration changes.

Comment: @Uncle_Timothy Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify download path when using headless mode in chromedriver. Also you have to wait until file will be downloaded. In code below you can find simple example how to wait file to be downloaded. I used regex to get name of the file.

```
import os

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

download_path = "your_download_path"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade ": True,
    'download.default_directory': download_path,
}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

spreadsheet_name = "Table 12. Labour force status by Sex, State and Territory - Trend, Seasonally adjusted and Original"
excel_xpath = f"//tr[contains(., '{spreadsheet_name}') and @class='listentry']//a[./img[contains(@alt, 'Excel')]]"

with driver:
    driver.get('https://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/6202.0Nov%202019?OpenDocument')

    download_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, excel_xpath)))
    href = download_button.get_attribute("href")

    # href of the file
    # https://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/meisubs.nsf/log?openagent&6202012.xls&6202.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&053D25DD395DF901CA2584D4001C70A5&0&Nov%202019&19.12.2019&Latest"
    file_name = re.findall(r"(?<=openagent&)(.*?)(?=&)", href)[0]

    download_button.click()

    for i in range(60):
        if not os.path.exists(f"{download_path}/{file_name}"):
            time.sleep(1)

    if not os.path.exists(f"{download_path}/{file_name}"):
        print("Failed to download", file_name, href)
```