# Selenium script that works perfectly in headed mode fails to work in headless mode (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I am trying to download a file using Selenium (Chrome Driver). I used a test website that contains a small sample audio file to download. The script works fine when used in a headed mode and the file downloads but fails in headless mode. I looked at some of the related questions and made sure that I used all mentioned options for the Chrome Driver but the following error pops up multiple times

I also tried the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599776/download-file-through-google-chrome-in-headless-mode) but it didn't work

```
[0125/104422.896:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to execute script from 'https://filesamples.com/detroitchicago/anaheim.js?gcb=2&cb=1' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable.", source: https://filesamples.com/formats/mp3 (0)
```

My code is as follows

```
download_dir = "path/to/downloads/"
driver_path = "path/to/driver"

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": download_dir,
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
})

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

base_url = "https://filesamples.com/formats/mp3"
driver.get(base_url)
xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/a"
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0].click()
```

There's no proper traceback, but I am fairly confident that the error is because of the `driver.get()` method because commenting out that line did not produce it

Chrome version - 87.0.4280.141
Chrome Driver version - 87.0.4280.88

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1080")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

you should set window size also

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately, it made no difference

Comment: updated the answer you should set window size also or scroll to that element

Comment: I already did those things before (check the code that I posted). I added the user agent option in addition to the other options I mentioned but it did not work

Comment: i checked it and its working no error is thrown

Comment: That's really strange. I am still seeing the same error. Are you able to download the mp3 file? I updated the code above, could you please check if everything looks fine?