# File download not working using selenium in python to download files in headless mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, reporting-services, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

So I am working on a project where I have to download hundreds of report from web server of SSRS. I wrote a program in python using selenium.
The requirement is that the reports should be downloaded in background.
I tried to get to the URL which downloads the report in excel format using
`driver.get(url)`
and the file was downloaded.

Whenever I connect to the URL a window pops up asking for user id and password.
[image]
So to address this I added two lines of code in chrome_options. [image]

Then the popup disappeared and the report was downloaded normally. But as soon as I add chrome_options(--headless) in the code the file is not downloaded only a console opens and it closes after a while[image]

So what I am saying is that this code works
[image]

But this code does not
[image]

I cannot understand why this is happening. Can anyone explain to me why my code does not work in headless mode?
Here's my full code (URL altered for privacy)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
import time
import datetime
import os

service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--auth-server-whitelist=*")
chrome_options.add_argument("--auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist=*")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=0")
service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

print('starting download')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("http://10.1.2.69:99/ReportServer")
time.sleep(3)
print('file downloaded')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium)

Comment: Are you under a corporate network?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

You need to use:

- For *chrome v96* till *chrome v108*:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
  ```
- For *chrome v109* and above:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
  ```

and execute your test.

> **See**: [DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('--headless') or add_argument('--headless=new') on Selenium 4.8.0 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367068/7429447)

---

Youe effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=chrome') # for chrome v96 to chrome v108
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new') # for chrome v109 and above
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

---

### References

A couple of helpful discussions:

- [Download file through Google Chrome in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57606294/7429447)

Comment: Hey it still does not work

Comment: Hey I have added my complete code for you to see. Its a rather short program. This code downloads file without headless=new but does not with headless=new.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266 (Downloading with chrome headless and selenium)

The Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode (in 2021). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

They later renamed the option in 2023 for Chrome 109 -> https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4

For Chrome 109 and above, the `--headless=new` flag will now allow you to get the full functionality of Chrome in the new headless mode, and you can even run extensions in it. (For Chrome versions 96 through 108, use `--headless=chrome`)

Usage: (Chrome 109 and above):

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Usage: (Chrome 96 through Chrome 108):

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

If something works in regular Chrome, it should now work with the newer headless mode too.

Comment: Yes I am using an older chromedriver I think that seems to be the issue