# How to get dynamic name of .zip file after download in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

Downloaded file from browser have dynamic name. How I can get a name of that file, so I can extract it and read the content of some files? I know some part of .zip file name, let say the first 4 characters.

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548041/selenium-give-file-name-when-downloading/56570364#56570364, you have options here for multiple languages. And it's been tested.

Comment: @supputuri I have my own download folder, but the logic is same, if you use the latest downloaded file, as I sow.