# How to specify name of file being downloaded from chrome in Selenium Java testing framework

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium Java in my automation framework and trying to download PDF from Chrome but specify name of that file is there an existing option?

here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:");
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium give file name when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548041/selenium-give-file-name-when-downloading)

Comment: Yes, I found the solution in one of the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution in this topic [Selenium give file name when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548041/selenium-give-file-name-when-downloading) answer from @supputuri
It is not possible to give the name to downloaded file, but below is the code how to get the name of downloaded file.

```
public String waitUntilDonwloadCompleted(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
  // Store the current window handle
  String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
  
  // open a new tab
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("window.open()");
 // switch to new tab
// Switch to new window opened
  for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
      driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
  }
 // navigate to chrome downloads
  driver.get("chrome://downloads");
  
  JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  // wait until the file is downloaded
  Long percentage = (long) 0;
  while ( percentage!= 100) {
      try {
          percentage = (Long) js1.executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value");
          //System.out.println(percentage);
      }catch (Exception e) {
        // Nothing to do just wait
    }
      Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
 // get the latest downloaded file name
  String fileName = (String) js1.executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('div#content #file-link').text");
 // get the latest downloaded file url
  String sourceURL = (String) js1.executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('div#content #file-link').href");
  // file downloaded location
  String donwloadedAt = (String) js1.executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.is-active.focus-row-active #file-icon-wrapper img').src");
  System.out.println("Download deatils");
  System.out.println("File Name :-" + fileName);
  System.out.println("Donwloaded path :- " + donwloadedAt);
  System.out.println("Downloaded from url :- " + sourceURL);
 // print the details
  System.out.println(fileName);
  System.out.println(sourceURL);
 // close the downloads tab2
  driver.close();
 // switch back to main window
  driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
  return fileName;
```

}